# incorrect use of url_for in flask

Tags: javascript, html, flask, nicegui

I have a `flask` server running which servers `HTML` pages with scripts stored in the static folder. This is an example script included in the header

```html
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/viewer.js')}}"></script>
```

and the `GET` requests are handled in the method

```py
@app.get("/view/<string:id>")
def view(id):
    ...
    return render_template("view.html", id=id)
```

If I type the address in my browser, I get the page rendered as expected

```
http://0.0.0.0:5500/view/1234
```

Now I want to embed this HTML in a `nicegui` application, for which I used `requests` library

```py
from nicegui import app, ui
import requests


r = requests.get('http://0.0.0.0:5500/view/1234')
ui.add_body_html(r.text)
ui.run()
```

But I get an error

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/static/js/viewer.js not found
```

`http://127.0.0.1:8080` is the address on which the `nicegui` application running. Also if I print out the text of the response, this is what I get

```html
<script src="/static/js/viewer.js"></script>
```

How can I correctly locate these javascript files?

**Edit 1:** The solution provided by [alexander-chereji](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22134798/alexander-chereji) worked but I also some javascript files with `socketio` clients. As an example

```js
$( window ).on( "load", function() {
    socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/view');
...
});
```

and similar to the previous issue, I guess the client is trying to connect to the address of nicegui app. I get errors like

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Or4vR54 not found
```

If I hardcode the flask's address in the script just to test

```js
socket = io.connect('http://0.0.0.0:5500/viz');
```

then I get an error on the flask side

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080 is not an accepted origin. # nicegui's address
127.0.0.1 - - "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Or5oYRP HTTP/1.1" 400 -
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your issue is related to the paths of static files in your NiceGUI application. When you use `ui.add_body_html(r.text)`, NiceGUI is rendering the HTML code on its own server, and it's not aware of the Flask server's static file paths.

To resolve this problem, you can modify the URLs of the static files in the HTML content before adding it to the NiceGUI application. You need to replace the relative paths with the absolute paths that are accessible from the NiceGUI server.

Here's an example of how you can do this:

```
from nicegui import ui
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  # Make sure to install BeautifulSoup

# Make a request to your Flask server
r = requests.get('http://192.168.1.26:5500/view/1234')

# Parse the HTML content
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

# Update the URLs of static files
static_elements = soup.find_all('script', {'src': True})
for element in static_elements:
    element['src'] = 'http://192.168.1.26:5500' + element['src']

# Add the modified HTML to NiceGUI
modified_html = str(soup)
ui.add_body_html(modified_html)
ui.run()
```

This code uses BeautifulSoup to parse the HTML content and updates the src attribute of script tags to use the absolute path of the Flask server. Also, make sure to install BeautifulSoup by running `pip install beautifulsoup4` (this is what I used).

I removed `app` from the imports since you don't use it in your code. Also it didn't work for me using 0.0.0.0, instead I changed it to 192.168.1.26. This should work for you as well.

Keep in mind that using this approach, your NiceGUI application will depend on the Flask server being accessible during its runtime. If the Flask server is not running, or if there are network issues, it can create problems with the NiceGUI app.

Comment: wow that worked!! excuse my ignorance, but when you type in `http://192.168.1.26:5500/view/1234` directly in the browser, how are the static files served in that case?

Comment: When you access the URL directly, the Flask server handles both the HTML page request and the subsequent requests for static files, serving the complete page with all associated resources. In your NiceGUI example, you needed to modify the HTML content to ensure that NiceGUI, which runs its own server, correctly locates and retrieves the static files when rendering the HTML. Was this the answer you were looking for?

Comment: yes that answer's my confusion! Thanks :) I have added an edit to my question regarding socketio connection